# Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 under 4G network

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, 4g

I know this question has been asked, unfortunately I have not found an answer that could save me.

Thanks for your time in advance.

My App uses `ASIHttpRequest` to call a `RESTful` service on a domain to login. Some of our customers are complaining that the App fails to login when their devices are connected to 4G network, but the APP runs happily under `WIFI`.

More details,

1. We can not reproduce this issue in one province. Our QA went to the province(I will call it the Issue Province) where the issue has been reported, and our QA can reproduce the issue easily. And The Issue Province is the only province where we can reproduce the issue.
2. With the same device and same APP version, the issue does not happen 100%.
3. Our QA reproduces the issue with iOS 9.3.1. I am sure if iOS version matters, though.

Following is the error log:

> Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x14e96a20 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8}}, NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred}

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897610/receiving-error-domain-kcferrordomaincfnetwork-code-2-when-attempting-to-read-from-readstream) post saying it should be a DNS issue, and according to the post, I have searched that 8 means "hostname nor servname provided, or not known" [here](http://opensource.apple.com//source/Libinfo/Libinfo-406.17/lookup.subproj/netdb.h).

But how should the issue be resolved for the Issue Province? Any configuration on device to set, or any code level thing I can do?

If I am supposed to provide more details, I will try.

Much appreciation! Our QA is still in the Issue Province, though.

Comment: One more detail, with the same device where the issue can ben reproduced, the same url can be opened with Safari and the response is what it should be.

Comment: Hi, any suggestion please?